# Plane wave through a shutter

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Why is it that when one considers some plane wave:
$$\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r},t\right)=\mathbf{E}_{0}e^{i\left(k_{0}z-\omega_{0}t\right)}$$ A shutter at some position (say $z=0$) that is opened for some interval of time $-T<t<T$ creates more frequencies in the power spectrum? Normally, the power spectrum will contain a $\delta^2(\omega-\omega_0)$ term, but I fail to understand what does a shutter that opens and closes does to the wave. How can I see it mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shutter you describe can be expressed via [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $\theta(\cdot)$ as

$$f(t)=\theta(t+T)-\theta(t-T).$$

To get the output wave, we multiply the input wave by this indicator function $f$ of the shutter. In the frequency spectrum the input wave gets convolved with the Fourier transform of $f$, which is proportional to $\operatorname{sinc}(\omega T).$ This convolution is the source of the extra frequencies in the output wave.